# Any public API available for Driving Licence(DL) number verification in India

Tags: web-services

I am working on a project where I need to verify the Driving License (DL) number of a driver. I have explored the internet but have not been able to find any official free API provided by the government. All I found were paid API (https://docs.attestr.com/attestr-docs/driving-license-check-api) and many other like this on Google search.

Can you please let me know any free official/unofficial API to verify Driving License(DL) in India.